# Number of bridges in a random graph $G(n,p)$.

Tags: graph-theory, random-graphs

What can we say about the number of bridges in a $G(n,p)$ random graph? For example, can we estimate the expected number of bridges in terms of $n$ and $p$?

Comment: What range of $p$ are you interested in?